# Can the Git Chef-repo be cloned from the Chef Server?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a question.
Can the Git Chef-repo be cloned from the Chef Server?
I mean, not the chef-repo template that can be downloaded from github,
I mean, if I have setup a private Chef Server, then can I clone the git repository that it manages internally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no notion of a "git" repository on the Chef Server. The Chef Server is an artifact server. It has no notion of SCM (whether it's git, svn, perforce, etc).

You can download individual artifacts, but no - the Chef Server is not a git remote.

Comment: You're quite correct, you can't do a "git clone". A compromise could be to use the "knife download" command and copy down the chef data in a chef repo layout (See: http://docs.opscode.com/knife_download.html)